# Multiple field validation in html form

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm designing a form to record a users bank details. On submit I want to ensure that they have given the appropriate details for sortcode, account number and pin (I know you should never record a pin its just for my project!). If any or all the fields are the incorrect length I want an error to appear. Here is my code but at the moment it does not seem to be catching any issues, perhaps someone could point out any errors?

```
<script>
    function formValidator(){
        var bankName = document.getElementById('bankName');
        var accName = document.getElementById('accName');
        var sortcode = document.getElementById('sortcode');
        var accNum = document.getElementById('accNum');
        var balance = document.getElementById('bal');
        var passhint = document.getElementById('passHint');
        var pin = document.getElementById('pin');
        var overdraft = document.getElementById('ODLimit');
        
        if(sortcodeLength(sortcode, 6)){
            if(accountNumLength(accNum, 8)){
                if(pinLength(pin, 4)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    function sortcodeLength(elem, val){
    var Input = elem.value;
    if(Input.length == val){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Please enter 6 digits for your sortcode");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    }
        
    function accountNumLength(elem, val){
            var Input = elem.value;
            if(Input.length == val){
                return true;
            }else{
            alert("Please enter 8 digits for your Account Number");
                elem.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

    function pinLength(elem, val){
    var Input = elem.value;
    if(Input.length == val){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Please enter 4 digits for your Pin");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And then I have my form that needs validated

```
    <form onClick='return formValidator()'>
Bank Name: <input type='text' id='bankName'/><br />
Acc Name: <input type='text' id='accName'/><br />
Sort Code: <input type='text' id='sortCode'/><br />
Acc Num: <input type='text' id='accNum'/><br />
Balance: <input type='text' id='bal'/><br />
PasswordHint: <input type='text' id='passHint'/><br />
Pin: <input type='text' id='pin'/><br />
Overdraft Limit: <input type='text' id='ODLimit'/><br />
<input type='submit' value='Check Form' />
</form>
```

What could I be doing wrong that this is not catching any errors in length of fields?

Comment: Thanks for coming back guys, I tried both answers but each time when I hit the submit button I still dont get any error even though I deliberately set the sortcode as only 3 digits

Comment: I've updated my answer because I found another problem with your code.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onsubmit event handler on your form not onclick

```
<form onsubmit='return formValidator();'>
```

Also you have a typo when finding the sort code field.  It has the wrong casing (which was causing a null ref error).

```
var sortcode = document.getElementById('sortCode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Move onclick event to the submit button from the form ie:
 onClick='return formValidator()'

```
<form >
Bank Name: <input type='text' id='bankName'/><br />
Acc Name: <input type='text' id='accName'/><br />
Sort Code: <input type='text' id='sortCode'/><br />
Acc Num: <input type='text' id='accNum'/><br />
Balance: <input type='text' id='bal'/><br />
PasswordHint: <input type='text' id='passHint'/><br />
Pin: <input type='text' id='pin'/><br />
Overdraft Limit: <input type='text' id='ODLimit'/><br />
<input type='submit' value='Check Form' onClick='return formValidator()' />
</form>
```